# How to remove looping elements using XSLT Transformations where some tag have no values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

```
 <DETAILS>
     <PUT>
        <RECORD>ABC_PQRST0123456-001_1</RECORD> 
        <NUMBER>4</NUMBER>
        <INST>1,2</INST>
      </PUT>
      <PUT>
        <RECORD>ABC_PQRST0123456-001_2</RECORD>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
     </PUT>
   </DETAILS>
```

How to remove the other loop elements from where INST don't have values.Can someone help me with xslt Transformation code to sort this

```
<PUT>
    <RECORD>ABC_PQRST0123456-001_2</RECORD>
    <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
  </PUT>
```

Comment: In XPath you can simply select `/DETAILS/PUT[not(INST)]`.

Comment: @Martin Could you please paste some sample code for reference.

Comment: There is the right XPath expression in my first comment, use it with `xsl:copy-of`.

Comment: Martin It is removing the value of INST but my requirement is We nee to remove the elements where INTS is not avalable as shown in below example.
<PUT>
        <RECORD>ABC_PQRST0123456-001_2</RECORD>
        <NUMBER>1</NUMBER>
     </PUT>

Comment: Then reverse the condition `<xsl:copy-of select="/DETAILS/PUT[INST]"/>`.

Comment: How to overcome extra spaces between elements<I V="145"/>
<I V="132"/>
</INST>
  
</PUT>
  
</DETAILS>

Comment: I don't see any `<I V="145"/>` element in your question's samples at all. Perhaps ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you describe:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PUT[not(INST)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- match but dont do anything -->
    <xsl:template match="PUT">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```